# Implement read only / write only database server architecture

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, sql-server-2008-r2

We have an ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application which consists of following:

- Website (MVC3)
- Data Access Service (WCF + EF)
- Database Server (SQL Server 2008 R2)

We were suggested to implement an architecture to the following for performance benefits:

- Web Server Cluster (Website + Data Access Service)

  - It has **Round Robin Load Balancing**
  - Each server in this cluster has a **Cache** (read-only) database
  - We have a set of SPs that we can distinctly divide into two categories - **Read SPs** and **Write SPs**
  - Each Read SP will connect to **Cache DB** and each Write SP will connect to **Write DB**
- Database Server(s) with Replication/Mirroring

  - This is the **Write DB**.
  - Whenever it changes, it propogates **all the changes** to all the **Cache DBs**
  - In addition to that, it has replication/mirroring implemented so it has backups when it goes down.

This is very rough idea and I am not sure it will give our system a performance boost.

The argument in favor of it was **80%** of the times, the operations are read-only. They can be made on **Cache DBs** (since there are configured to be read-only, they are faster). The other **20%** can be made on **Write DBs**.

But, I have following questions:

- **Read-Only Configuration**: can we actually configure **Cache DBs** to be read-only? Since **Write DB** will need to push changes to them whenever it changes.
- **Sync**: with all this complexity over the network, how easy it is to make sure that everything is in sync? 
  **Network Latency**: and what about network overheads to keep everything in sync?
- **Complexity and Maintenance**: is it really worth the added maintenance overheads and the added complexity to the system?

Answer (score 0):

Nice design, it is similar to a discussion I once had on how to create an audit database where everyone can add but it is impossible to update or delete.

You cannot make change the database if the status is set to read-only, so you cannot take advantage of that feature in SQL Server. I think the real advantage of a read-only database is that you can ignore locking when performing a query and you can create specialized indexes, knowing that nothing will change. According to http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2007/10/01/performance-impact-setting-a-database-to-read-only.aspx (for SQL 2005) the gain in setting it to read-only is not that big.

If you are willing to sacrifice some consistency you can lower the Isolation Level of your queries to e.g. Read committed so that fewer locks are generated.

One advantage of creating two databases is that it gives you the ability to separate the databases across different database servers. This would enable you to guarantee that a Write operation succeed even if the CacheDb server has 100% CPU load and network load.

I assume that the Write DB would allow all users to write (and perhaps even disallow read?) while the Cache DB would only give users read priviledges, with a specific service account having write priviledges.

Synchronization of the content between Write DB and Cache DB can be made using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) and I don't think it would be so hard to design the transfer logic. Having both servers in the same building with gigabit network between them will mean that you latency in the transfer will be low.